# Liberar memoria al cerrar un formulario C# ¿Cada cuánto tiempo se llama al GC?

Tags: c#, telerik

Creo que la aplicación que estoy desarrollando tiene una fuga de memoria y estoy tratando de averiguar donde puede estar el problema.

Estamos utilizando las librerías WinForms de Telerik para tener un entorno gráfico distinto y no se si el problema puede venir derivado de eso.

La cuestión es que simplemente al abrir la ventana de Acerca de (a continuación pondré el código) cuando cierro la ventana, viendo el administrador de recursos del Visual Studio, no veo que la memoria disminuya y si sigo abriendo y cerrando la ventana la memoria sigue subiendo. Al rato, pasa el recolector de basura y libera parte de la memoria, pero no toda.

¿Cómo debe cerrarse apropiadamente un formulario? ¿Qué tipos de variables deberían hacer un dispose (obviamente todas las que tengan dicha función?

Pongo el código del Acerca de:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Aplicacion
{
    public partial class frmAcercaDe : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
    {

        public frmAcercaDe()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string cVersion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
            this.lblVersion.Text = "Versión " + cVersion;
        }

        ~frmAcercaDe()
        {
            // Según he leído este es el destructor, y poniendo una parada aqui
            // se puede saber si el destructor es llamado.
            // La parada no se dispara nunca.
        }

        private void cbbAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void frmAcercade_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyData)
            {
                case Keys.Escape:
                case Keys.Enter:
                    cbbAceptar.PerformClick();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void frmAcercaDe_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Usamos esta variable para no permitir abrir más de una vez
            // el formulario si ya está abierto
            frmPrincipal.lHayInstanciaAcercaDe = true;
        }

        private void frmAcercaDe_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            frmPrincipal.lHayInstanciaAcercaDe = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Y parte del codigo de frmPrincipal:

```
// Los usings
using ...

public partial class frmPrincipal : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
{
    public static bool lHayInstanciaAcercaDe = false;

    public frmPrincipal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ...

    private void cbbAcercaDe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!lHayInstanciaAcercaDe)
        {
            frmAcercaDe ofrmAcercaDe = new frmAcercaDe();
            ofrmAcercaDe.MdiParent = this;
            ofrmAcercaDe.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.MdiChildren.Length; i++)
            {
                if (this.MdiChildren[i].Name == "frmAcercaDe")
                {
                    this.MdiChildren[i].Activate();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Aparte del problema de la ventana de Acerca de, que en mi opinión no debería pasar, otra cuestión que tenemos es que nuestra aplicación trabaja con muchas tablas y por cada una tenemos un formulario de tabla y un formulario de registro. Como por cada tabla normalmente se añadirá más de un registro una vez abierto, para que la carga de la ventana de registro sea más rápida, al inicializar el formulario de tabla, inicializamos también el de registro. Puede que el problema venga derivado de trabajar de esta forma. Para que lo entendais es algo así.

```
namespace Aplicacion
{
    public partial class frmTabla : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
    {
        frmRegistro ofrmRegistro = new frmRegistro();

        ...

        public frmTabla()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ...

        private void cbbAnadir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ofrmRegistro.ShowDialog();
            if (ofrmRegistro.Aceptado)
            {
                ActualizarRejilla();
            }
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yo probaria a ver en el evento Closing que es lo que esta pasando.

Comment: ¿Ver qué exactamente?

Comment: simplemente como evoluciona la memoria, intentaria alli ver que recursos se estan usando para ver como liberarlos. quizas esta documentacion te pueda aydar de alguna manera. https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Gracias, intentaré echarle un vistazo cuando pueda

Comment: Estios temas suelen ser complejos. Pero hay algo que no entiendo en tu `frmAcercaDe`. Para que necesitas `lHayInstanciaAcercaDe`? Como estas llamando al formulario? Como accedes a `frmPrincipal` desde el AcercaDe? Lo digo porque lo normal es que desde el formulario principal enseñases el AcercaDe de forma modal y de esa manera ni tienes que preocuparte por controlar otras instancias ni necesitas acceder al formulario principal para nada

Comment: Cuando desde `frmPrincipal` se pulsa en el boton para abrir `frmAcercaDe`, comprobamos si esa variable está a `true`. Si lo está buscamos en las ventanas abiertas (`frmPrincipal` es un formulario de tipo mdi) y le asignamos el foco. Si no lo está simplemente la abrimos. Se que hubiera sido más fácil que el 'frmAcercaDe` fuera una ventana modal, pero es así como estamos trabajando todas las otras ventanas.

Comment: Si,entiendo. Pero como teneis acceso a `frmPrincipal` desde `frmAcercaDe`?

Comment: La variable `lHayInstanciaAcercaDe` es una variable estática que se encuentra en `frmPrincipal`.

Comment: Si,perdona que insista. Desde el frmPrincipal se muestra el frmAcercaDe. Asi que desde frmAcercaDe no se tiene acceso al frmPrincipal a no ser que a.-hagais una busqueda de la ventana o b.- accedais al Parent del formulario. En ambos casos, necesitaríais una nueva variable `frmPrincipal`. Resumiendo, el código que nos pones tal como está no compilaría ya que `frmPrincipal` no está definido. Si insisto es porque si falta código es posible que ahi estuviera la causa del "memory leak"

Comment: No pasa nada, he añadido a mi pregunta la parte del `frmPrincipal` que considero relevante. El código compila, no se si por no querer ponerlo todo se me habrá olvidado escribir algo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema puede ser complejo principalmente porque el GC se ejecuta de manera aleatoria. Pero aqui algunos puntos a tener en cuenta:

## 1 : Form.Dispose() no ejecuta el destructor

Segun la documentacion:

> Dispose deja el [`Component`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx) en un estado inusable lo que habilita
>   que el *GC pueda reclamar* la memoria ocupada por el `Component`

Lo que probablemente significa que el `Component` dentro el Form se asigne a `null` y cuando el GC se ejecute(0.5, 1, 5, 10, 20, 30 minutos de espera) reclama la memoria pero no que llamara el destructor.

## 2 Ejecutar GC.Collect() no te asegura la llamada del desctructor immediatamente

[Cuando declaras un objecto con un destructor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors), la referencia del destructor se guarda en un queue de destructores que son llamados cuando el `GC` se ejecuta pero eso puede tomar tiempo, no necesariamente cuando asignas el objecto a null. Incluso llamar `GC.Collect()` es mala idea porque los lags que puede causar a tu aplicacion que seria peor.

---

Tienes que detenerte y mirar que recursos tu aplicacion esta utilizando. 
Llamar Dispose() en las conexiones de base de datos tambien puede ayudarte mucho. Si muestras datos en un ListView, asegurate de que antes de salir del form limpies la tabla y los objectos relacionados a ella.

El GC es algo complicado y ejecutarlo puede ser un dolor de cabeza si no se sabe utilizar por lo que te recomiendo que lo dejes trabajar a el. Por algo [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) es `managed code`. CRL se encarga de llamar el GC cuando sea necesario. Intenta adoptar el [patron Disposable](https://www.google.com.do/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiWpqWT5YPVAhWGyyYKHY-fBRMQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FArticles%2F15360%2FImplementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P&usg=AFQjCNHqCTg3RfCM1uQf3p5TFFOxN_BfGA&cad=rjt) y libera todo en cuando puedas.

Suerte.

Comment: Entonces, el GC se ejecuta aleatoriamente. He probado a poner `GC.Collect()` después de cerrar la ventana y efectivamente parte de la memoria se ha recuperado, lo que supongo que significa que cuando al GC quiera ejecutarse (que podría ser cuando el ordenador se quede sin memoria por ejemplo) debería funcionar. Por lo que he visto no se recomienda ejecutar `GC.Collect()` manualmente, pero si puedo mientras estoy desarrollado utilizarlo tras hacer los `Dispose()` para comprobar si el GC los recogería cuando fuera necesario y en caso afirmativo quitarlo, ¿no?

Comment: Eso esta a decision tuya. Yo personalemente dejaria al GC funcionar por el lag que puede causar. Dispose fue creado para liberar objetos no manejados como la conexion a la base de datos y sockets. Los objetos del CLR el `GC` se encarga de eliminarlos automáticamente si nota que no se utilizan. Así que no seria tan necesario ejecutar `GC.Collect()`. Pero como dije, esta a decision tuya.

Comment: Sí, se que es malo, por eso digo que puedo ponerlo, comprobar que el GC obviamente lo recogería y después lo quito. Si el GC no lo recoge seguir depurando hasta funcione y después quitarlo. Gracías de todas formas.

Answer (score 1):

Una de las cosas que puedes hacer para que se libere la memoria en el momento que dejas de usar el objeto es usar el objeto con una intruccion de `using` y así siempre y cuando el elemento tenga implementado `IDisposable`, al termianr el bloque `using` este automaticamente llamará al `dispose` del objeto el cual se encargará de liberar la memoria.

Un ejemplo seria:

```
//declaramos el using y la variable a usar
using(frmAcercaDe miForm = new frmAcercaDe())
{
     //mostramos el formulario 
     miform.ShowDialog();
}
```

Esto te servirá siempre y cuando el objeto tenga implementado el interfaz `IDisposable` que por lo que puedo comprobar [aquí](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/api/html/m_telerik_wincontrols_ui_radform_dispose.htm) no tendrías problemas.

Otra manera de liberar la memoria sin usar el bloque `using` sería llamando al `.Dispose()` al finalizar el uso del formulario

Comment: Sigue haciendo lo mismo. Quizás sea ya un problema de `Telerik`, que hace que tarde en pasar el recolector y yo estoy complicándome por algo ajeno. De todas formas, si no usara un `.ShowDialog()` sino un '.Show()', el `.Dispose()` debería hacerlo en el evento `FormClosed` de `frmAcercaDe`, ¿no?

Comment: Daría igual que uses un ´.show()´ o un ´.showDialog()´ la cosa es hacerlo en el objeto que quieres liberar pero no dentro de él. Es decir, el ´.Dispose()´ debe ser llamado cuando el formulario este cerrado, o lo que sería lo mismo después de ese `.show()`

Comment: Supongo que con un `Show()` tendría que tener algun tipo de control, ¿no?. Mientras que el `ShowDialog()` interrumpe el proceso y no continua hasta que se cierra la ventana, si pongo el `Dispose()` justo después del `Show()` se cierra inmediatamente.

Comment: Toda la razón,  entonces tendrás que hacer que cuando la cierres desde donde la abriste hacer el `.Dispose()`